# Django failed to run test server: ImportError: No module named hitcount

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I've been working with it recently for a group project. I have it successfully installed and correctly configured - it worked fine when I tried to create my own test projects, yet when I started to run the test server on the project pulled from my teammate's repo it raised the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10c9e6578>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named hitcount
```

Can anybody help me find out how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing hitcount:

```
pip install django-hitcount
```